# Slang word(s) for pretty? (pretty slang synonyms)

Tags: slang

I know I sometimes can use `fancy` which is quite a nice word, but I look for slang word, synonym of pretty/fancy.

Basically, I need those words for my webpage. I wrote a HTML webpage, where I have a CSS element I called FancyFooter. Now I need another word, for pretty header of my webpage and look for a word that would express how "awesome" my header is.

Comment: Pretty and fancy don't mean the same thing. Which meaning do you want to express? Can you use the word in an example sentence so we can try to get your intended meaning from context?

Comment: Basically, I need those words for my webpage :) I wrote a HTML webpage, where I have a CSS element I called `FancyFooter`. Now I need another word, for pretty header of my webpage and look for a word that would express how awesome my header is ;)

Comment: After reading your comment, I changed the link to look at fancy rather than pretty.

Comment: HotHeader keeps your alliteration.

Comment: @StoneyB: thanks, I really liked it! :) I think I will use HotHeader, cheers :)

Comment: The next time you ask a question, be sure to provide more details. Your original question asks for a synonym for pretty/fancy. Pretty _what_? Pretty drapes? A pretty car? A fancy chandelier? A pretty ball gown, like Cinderella wore? A fancy chess set? I wouldn't necessarily use the same words for all of those. Then, in a comment, you let us know it's for a webpage. Why did you omit that from the original question?

Comment: There's also HeavenlyHeader ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fancy doesn't exactly work as a slang word for pretty.  It means above the ordinary.  So, if you have a fancy car, it may be ugly and it may not, but it's certainly expensive.

Fancy can be used sarcastically, too, to poke fun at people who think that they're above average.  I've found this to be quite popular in Texas in particular; if someone is "a little too fancy for me" it's a way of saying that someone thinks he's so far above my social station that I can't have anything to do with him.  You'll also hear about "fancy attitudes", "fancy habits" and so on.

Next, if you want to find slang words, consult a slang dictionary or thesaurus.  [Here's](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/thesaurus/words+meaning+expensive,+fancy,+high+quality.html) a place to get you started.